# Audio doesn't play when window isn't focused

Tags: electron, elm

I have an application written in Elm that plays Pandora music that is displayed in Electron. Most of the time when a song ends it moves on to the next song as usual, but occasionally if the window isn't focused and is behind another one (generally when I'm using only a single monitor) my progress bar will keep moving but the audio will not play until I focus the window. Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this?

```
          onEnded
                (case (gm.currentStation) of
                    Just station ->
                        station.id

                    Nothing ->
                        ""
                )
            , id "songAudio"
            , src
                (case (List.head gm.songQueue) of
                    Just song ->
                        song.audioURL

                    Nothing ->
                        ""
                )
            , autoplay True
            ]
            [] 
onEnded : String -> Attribute Msg
onEnded stationId =
    Html.Events.on "ended"
        (Decode.succeed (SongEnded stationId))


( { gm
            | songQueue = (List.drop 1 gm.songQueue)
            , previousSongs =
                (case List.head gm.songQueue of
                    Just song ->
                        song

                    Nothing ->
                        { songTitle = ""
                        , trackLength = 0
                        , rating = 0
                        , audioURL = ""
                        , artistName = ""
                        , albumTitle = ""
                        , albumArt = ""
                        , trackToken = ""
                        }
                )
                    :: gm.previousSongs
            , currentTime = 0
            , isPlaying = True
          }
        , cmds
            [ if List.length gm.songQueue == 2 then
                Http.send LoadedNextSongs
                    (SongApi.getNext stationId gm.authToken False)
              else
                Cmd.none
            ]
        )
```

Most of the time it continues playing the song as normal, but occasionally it doesn't begin the song until I refocus the window. (The progress bar keeps counting though, so the code that is causing it to play should be working.)

Comment: Can you verify that Elm is re-rendering when the page is not focused and the new audio source becomes available?

"Most browsers stop sending requestAnimationFrame() callbacks to background tabs or hidden <iframe>s in order to improve performance and battery life." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API#Policies_in_place_to_aid_background_page_performance)